# How to find a object in by name in the properties?

Tags: qgis, color, qgis-2.12

I would like to change the color of one object in the shapefile. I have done it with every object of interest and it worked so far. But this one I can’t find by name in the properties. Is it possible to click on that shapefile with the “information button” and go directly to the properties where I can change the color? So far I couldn’t figure it out.

I am using the QGIS 2.12.3 - Lyon Version.

Comment: What do you use? QGIS, ESRI, ... ?

Comment: I use QGIS 2.12.3. - Lyon.  I am not sure if i could express myself correctly. I have a big shapefile with a lot of objects in it. I changed the color of the whole shapefile in grey and just a few, important ones, I wanted to change in color. This I did with the properties, where I searched for each name and changed the color one by one. Now I have one object that I can’t find in the property list by name. So I was wondering if there is an option to get by clicking on the object directly to its properties to change the color?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with additional details. Potential answerers do not always read the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You could just **select** the feature you want to change the color of, **enable editing**, change its **name** (give it anything you can identify), **save** edits and then **style** the object by its name like you have been doing.

Comment: I did it as you said and then it was pretty easy :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

1. Mark the layer (the shapefile) in your Layer Panel
2. Use the `Identify Feature` courser

   [image: identfy feature]
3. Click on the "object" you try to get the properties from

[image: example]

4. Go to `Layer Properties -> Style` an change the colors there (depending on the attribute, in my example it depends on the value of `area`)

[image: properties]

[image: style]

---

5. (optional) To narrow down you object you can use the [Query Builder](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/da/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html) (`Properties -> General`). Set the filter using an unique identifier like the ID.

[image: query builder]

Comment: I did that, but where can I change its color? This way I just get the attribute list I thought...

Comment: The color depends on the attribute! So if you know the attributes of your object you can change it in `Layer Properties -> Style`

Comment: My shapefile is very big and I have it classified by name. So in there I cant find that name. I could classify it by object id, but woudn't I lose everything that I have done so far?

Comment: But you can see the `name` with the feature `Identify Feature`? If it is very big don't use the object id!!! Just copy or add the shape file again to your panel and add under `Properties -> General -> ` [`Query Builder`](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/da/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html) a selection for you object. This way it will only display one element.

Comment: By the way it seems like you should read some more tutorials, this information are all out there!

Comment: I actually read a lot, but since I am new, I am already struggeling with small things. I tried as you told me in the Querry Builder, but when I did it, all my other objects, where I changed already the color, changed them again to grey. I guess it’s a mistake in my formula, but I don’t know how to write it: “Biotop” like “Nasswiese im Lachen” or how do I search for my object?

Comment: `like` is like a search term... so it would be probably `"Biotop" like "%Nasswiese im Lachen%"`. As you are a starter don't make it complicated, use the object id eg. `"osm_id" = 321`

Comment: Thank you for your help, in the end I did it as suggested by Hasan Mustafa, because I am still pretty lost with the Querry Builder!  But thanks a lot for your help!